# APA style footnote explanation

Tags: academic-writing, apa

What is the recommended way of explaining terms, like *psychometrics*, that are not essential to the paper (APA style)?

Is it possble to add a footnote plus reference to explain the term? 
Or explain it in-text inside parentheses?